# Seam Equivalent of Spring PersistenceUnitPostProcessor

Tags: spring, jpa, seam

We have a very comfortable setup using JPA through Spring/Hibernate, where we attach a PersistenceUnitPostProcessor to our entity manager factory, and this post processor takes a list of project names, scans the classpath for jars that contain that name, and adds those jar files for scanning for entities to the persistence unit, this is much more convenient than specifying  in persistence.xml since it can take partial names and we added facilities for detecting the different classpath configurations when we are running in a war, a unit test, an ear, etc.

Now, we are trying to replace Spring with Seam, and I cant find a facility to accomplish the same hooking mechanism. One Solution is to try and hook Seam through Spring, but this solution has other short-comings on our environment. So my question is: Can someone point me to such a facility in Seam if exists, or at least where in the code I should be looking if I am planning to patch Seam?

Thanks.

Comment: @shipmaster I do not think so but if you get your goal, share it with us. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in a Java EE container like JBoss 6 (and I really recommend so), all you need is to package your beans into a jar, place a META-INF/persistence.xml inside it and place the jar into your WAR or EAR package. All @Entity annotated beans inside the jar will be processed.

For unit-testing, you could point the `<jar-file>` element to the generated `.class` output directory and Hibernate will also pick the Entities. Or even configure during runtime using `Ejb3Configuration.addAnnotatedClass`;

`@see` http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html